# targetFramework-Attribute... higher Version 4

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-4.7.1

I installed Windows Server 2016 Core with IIS and ASPNET45.

When starting my app this error shows up.

[image: Servererror in application /]

```
Line 12:
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1"/>
```

Note: 
Info says .NET Framework 4 and ASP.NET 4.7.2 are installed.
Also AppPool is set to runtime Version v4.0